# With GCC, can I disable -Wframe-larger-than on a per-function basis?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-warnings

Using GCC, is it possible to specify a set of functions that are exempt from -Wframe-larger-than? (For example, main.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

GCC supplies you with pragmas for this purpose:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.2/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html#Diagnostic-Pragmas

Currently it won't do exactly what you want, since it seems to do it on a file by file basis, but in the next version of gcc (4.6), it appears as though it is context aware:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html#Diagnostic-Pragmas

Comment: It can work on a function-by-function basis.  From the docs: "GCC keeps track of the location of each pragma, and issues diagnostics according to the state as of that point in the source file. Thus, pragmas occurring after a line do not affect diagnostics caused by that line."

Comment: @Carl: Actually, those docs are for the current development version (4.6), so its not applicable to 4.5, if you check the link I gave.

Comment: oh ok.  I didn't see any versioning on that doc, actually.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick (specifically, `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wframe-larger-than="`). Though now I want GCC 4.6 even more.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit old, but I came across it looking for the same answer, so I thought I'd post my solution (found by trial and error):

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wframe-larger-than="

void func() 
{ int x[2000] = {}; printf("%d",x[1]); }    

#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

seems to work.  For some reason, trying to use `diagnostic warning` did not work.  It does not seem possible to change the stack size that generates the warning.  Also, you need the = at the end.  Maybe the next guy will find this and save themselves some time :).   This is 4.6.2 (on an ARM cross compiler).

John

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [GCC diagnostic pragma](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html).